# can you toggle "show my caller id" switch with code on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios7, telephony

I am looking for a way within latest Xcode to toggle the "show my caller ID" switch that is normally found within "Settings-Phone-Show My Caller ID".

I have a simple command to call out (using the "@tel://" etc...)
I have this working and can call out from my app (which is just a simple number pad and call button). I'm just using this to learn code thru examples - not for distribution.

However, would be nice to have a toggle switch or button on same page as number pad to "show my caller ID". That way, I could block caller ID without having to go back thru settings-phone menu each time.

Tried to look thru examples here and xcode tutorials, but can't find an answer.

Thanks in advance, Kris

Comment: Xcode is an IDE. It doesn't do anything on your phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on non-jailbroken iOS devices. You will need to look through the plist files on your jailbroken iPhone. You can check in **/System/Library/CoreServices/**, or anything to do with `Preferences`, or `CoreTelephopny.`

Also, it should go without saying, but you won't be able to use such a feature in an App Store release since this is strictly **Private API**.

Comment: hey thanks - will try that. No i'm just trying something on my phone to make it easier to call out, not for distribution.